# Algorithmic representation of the Spin (and Pin) group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algorithms

Performing algorithmic computations in $\mathit{SO}_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathit{O}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is easy: its elements are represented by $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices of reals so, assuming we have some representation of real numbers¹ we can deal with rotations in a computer by storing of the order of $n^2$ such reals.

But what about the double covers $\mathit{Spin}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathit{Pin}^{\pm}_n(\mathbb{R})$ of these groups?  The only way I know how to represent them algorithmically is by their action on the spin (or when $n$ is even, half-spin) representation² which is of dimension $2^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}$, so something of the order of $2^n$ reals (or complex numbers but no matter).  This is unreasonable as $n$ gets large.  But nobody says we have to represent them just using a matrix acting on spinors: maybe we could use a rotation matrix and a simplified representation of a path from the identity to the given matrix (though it seems like it would make multiplication terribly complicated to work out).  So anyway:

**Question:** are there known and workable algorithms to perform computations in $\mathit{Spin}_n(\mathbb{R})$ (and ideally, $\mathit{Pin}^{\pm}_n(\mathbb{R})$ as well) for large $n$, using storage that does not grow exponentially in $n$?

(I'm deliberately leaving the question a bit vague, because I don't want to ask about specific algorithmic bounds or make specific assumptions about how real numbers are represented: anything reasonable is fine.  “Large” $n$ means around $100$, say, so that $n^2$ is perfectly manageable but $2^n$ is not.)

*Footnotes:*

1. Which, of course, is its own can of worms, but I'd like to leave that one closed for this question; maybe we're dealing with exact algebraics, or maybe we have a black box representation of reals, or more realistically we're dealing with floats and are willing to tolerate some level of numerical errors.
2. The double meaning of “representation” (i.e., “algorithmic representation” and “(linear) representation” as in representation theory) is unfortunate here, since the whole point is that we don't necessarily need to use a linear representation to obtain an algorithmic representation.

Comment: One doesn't need to work in the full Clifford algebra to represent elements in Pin and Spin, since one can work with the definition as a product of $r$ vectors (as in Lawson-Michelson page 18).  I don't know what the optimal bounds would be for $r$ but at any rate it is at most the dimension of the original vector space.  Of course there is no uniqueness here, but at any rate one gets fewer parameters than $2^n$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Good point. But while this provides a representation of the elements of the groups, it's not fully clear to me how it can be used to compute products (we can reduce the problem to re-expressing the product of $r+1$ nonzero vectors as a product of $r$ vectors in the Clifford algebra… maybe by computing the rotation matrix, writing it as a product of reflexions, and then “checking the sign”?). Also, while non-uniqueness is not a problem *per se*, I should have added in the question that one should be able to test equality (or some kind of numerical proximity).

Comment: Here the homomorphism to O(n) could help.  If they hit the same orthogonal matrix, there is a 50% chance they are the same :-)

Comment: Testing for equality can be done if one can compute inverses, and also can test for the neutral element, which surely we can do here?

Comment: @IliaSmilga Holy shit! I had completely forgotten I had asked this already. This is embarrassing.

Comment: I guess this could happen to me as well :-) In any case it is a great question, which definitely deserves to be asked at least once! And I was happy to see it again - it reminded me that it is still unanswered and got me thinking a bit further :-)